# Flutter package - reducing the number of imports in a project

Tags: flutter, dart, package

I'm creating a Flutter package to facilitate the process of standardizing the interface of my apps. When I go to test a new  `Widget`  made in the package, a new  `import`  appears in the file.
How can I make just a single import call all  `Widgets` ?

```
import 'package:design_system/buttons/groupButton.dart';
import 'package:design_system/design_system.dart';
import 'package:design_system/buttons/elevatedButton.dart';
import 'package:design_system/buttons/gradientButton.dart';
import 'package:design_system/colorPallette/collor_pallette.dart';
```

All child library widgets are separated by folder(button in buttons folder).

This is the main file, where I call Widgets.

```
library design_system;

export 'buttons/groupButton.dart';
export 'buttons/elevatedButton.dart';
export 'buttons/gradientButton.dart';
```

Comment: you are going the right way, just import the last one.dart

Comment: But I would like it to stay with the Material's imports. A single import brings all the Material components.

Comment: as you did on second, you need to export the created file and and import this file, are you trying to export source file as well, like `package:flutter/material.dart';`?